# C# REST api method invoking

Tags: c#, rest, model-view-controller

Given this code in a C# REST api. A request comes in and a method is invoked as below

```
using (MethodInformation _methodInformation = new MethodInformation())
{
    _methodInformation.ObjectType = _functionElement.Type;
    _methodInformation.Method = _functionElement.Method;
    _methodInformation.RequestStream = ConvertRequestContent();
    _methodInformation.RequestParameters = ConvertRequestParameters();
    _object = _methodInformation.InstanceMethodInvoker(null);
}
```

All data from the request is packed up in to _methodInformation.RequestStream.

We now lose the default model binding functionality that the MVC framework provides.

Is this a legitimate way to go about this, bearing in mind we cannot use model binding and have to reconstruct the strongly typed objects from the RequestStream.

What advantages can we get from implementing the API this way?